# Problem with babel and fontspec

Tags: fontspec, babel

I've just had a problem on using babel with lualatex (or xelatex as well) and fontspec in the context of latin and cyrillic alphabets. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Heuristica}%
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\newcommand*\English{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}

\textup{\Russian Мороз и солнце, день чудесный}

\English\textit{The sea is calm to-night.}
\end{document}
```

And here's the resulting .pdf:

[image]

As one can see, the font  used for the English part of the text is `Computer Modern`, not `Heuristica`, and there's not even italic where  it's supposed to be italic.

However, if I change the order of the languages (`[russian, english]`, everything is fine:

[image]

If I compile with `pdflatex`, modifying accordingly the preamble and using the type 1 versions of the fonts instead of the opentype, everything is fine whatever the order of the languages. I tried with some other fonts, same problem. Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Comment: `poetrytex` is irrelevant.

Comment: @egreg: True, I simply took my answer to a question. I''ll simplify my question.

Comment: Load `fontspec` after `babel`. But note that the `fontspec` manual says that `babel` 'is not really supported' and recommends `polyglossia` (page 4). Nonetheless, it works if you change the order of loading.

Comment: @cfr: Didn't think of that, though I knew the trick for the French language, but the reason is active characters. Works lke a charm! Is this documented somewhere? If you make your comment an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Bernard Done though it is really superseded by egreg's answer...

Comment: A somewhat relevant comment: I always start my package loading with `\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg: Yes, but it was once recommended to load babel towards the end of the preamble. So…?

Comment: Hmmm. Okay. Do you know where this is stated? I would like to now why that is. `:)`

Comment: I can't remember. I think the recommendation isn't valid any more, and maybe it was in connection withe the `frenchb` option  and active characters.

Comment: Works fine for me (babel 3.9k). Which version are you using? Note the latest release revises the font encoding stuff, which in some cases leaded to wrong results even with pdfTeX (as explained in the manual). In fact, `\latinencoding` is now deprecated.

Comment: @ Javier Bezos: I use 3.9k. But the problem arises with `Xe/LuaLaTeX`. Do you mean it works fine for you with these engines? As for the input encoding, I've been using utf8 for some years. If I understand well, internally, there's an `EU1/EU2` font encoding, and the problem is connected with that.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it works with both xe and lua, but I've realized I'm using an old release of `fontspec` (which has been updated recently). Perhaps something changed in the latest `fontspec`.

Comment: @JavierBezos: Yes, I have version 2.4a (packaged around 22/6 in MiKTeX).

Comment: Found -- `fontspec` formerly made sure `\latinencoding` was EUx _after_ loading the `.aux` file, but that's not true any more. Which means now `babel` must be loaded before. I presume this change in `fontspec` will break lots of documents :-(.

Comment: (Note. I meant the `\AtBeginDocument` hook, not the `aux` file.)

Comment: Javier's contacted me by email about this — if anyone has ideas on how it can be improved, please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

egreg's answer now explains *why* this works which I didn't understand when I posted it as a comment.

If you load `fontspec` *after* `babel`, then it all works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[british,russian]{babel}
\newcommand*\English{\selectlanguage{british}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Heuristica}%
\usepackage{poetrytex}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\poetryheadings}{\pagestyle{myheadings} \markboth{}{}}
\English
\begin{poem}{Title}{Author\\2014}
\textup{\Russian Мороз и солнце, день чудесный}\\
\textit{The sea is calm to-night.}
\end{poem}

\end{document}
```

[image: Heuristica]

But note that the `fontspec` manual describes `babel` as 'not really supported' and recommends `polyglossia` (page 4). I assume they mean for languages supported by the latter which is not all of them but does include Russian.

Answer (score 10):

The relevant part from `babel.def` is

```
\AtEndOfPackage{\edef\latinencoding{\cf@encoding}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \gdef\latinencoding{OT1}%
  \ifx\cf@encoding\bbl@t@one
    \xdef\latinencoding{\bbl@t@one}%
  \else
    \@ifl@aded{def}{t1enc}{\xdef\latinencoding{\bbl@t@one}}{}%
  \fi
  }
```

Let's see what happens: at the end of the loading of `babel`, the instruction

```
\edef\latinencoding{\cf@encoding}
```

is performed; since `fontspec` recognizes being called by XeLaTeX, it sets `\cf@encoding` to `EU1`. This might be needed from packages loaded later on.

Then, at begin document, `\latinencoding` is set temporarily to `OT1` and then the value of `\cf@encoding` is examined again, because it might have changed. If it is `T1`, then `\latinencoding` is changed to `T1`; the same is done if `t1enc.def` has been loaded. Since in your case `\cf@encoding` is `EU1` and `t1enc` has not been loaded, nothing happens and `\latinencoding` keeps its value `OT1`.

Indeed, you get warnings from LaTeX such as

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/Heuristica(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

that is issued when `\English` is done, because `babel` executes `\edef\encodingdefault{\latinencoding}`, in order to be able to use Latin characters.

This doesn't happen if, more correctly, `fontspec` is loaded *after* `babel`, because `fontspec` (actually `fontspec-xetex.sty`) does

```
\tl_set_eq:NN \cyrillicencoding \g_fontspec_encoding_tl
\tl_set_eq:NN \latinencoding    \g_fontspec_encoding_tl
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \tl_set_eq:NN \cyrillicencoding \g_fontspec_encoding_tl
  \tl_set_eq:NN \latinencoding    \g_fontspec_encoding_tl
 }
```

and `\g_fontspec_encoding_tl` is `EU1`, so the faulty redefinition of `\latinencoding` to `OT1` is overridden.

Comment: Crystal clear explanation, thanks! Of course with `polyglossia`, I didn't have the problem.

Comment: I know I should (and would) have upvoted your answer, but I had promised @cfr since his solved my problem.

Comment: @Bernard She wrote her comment while I was analyzing the problem, knowing for sure that `fontspec` has to be loaded after `babel`. As somebody in chat would say, I tend to write overlong answers. ;-) You can accept just one answer, but upvote as many as you want; not that it would really count for my reputation, unless you do it tomorrow. ;-)

Comment: I also tend to check the ins and outs of a question before answering:). Comment aside, I'm afraid I mixed up upvoting and accepting an answer (not yet very familiar with this system…)