# Babel before or after fontspec?

Tags: packages, fontspec, babel

Paying keen attention to package loading order, I wonder if `babel` should be loaded *before* or *after* `fontspec`. Neither manual carries information on the loading order.

Furthermore, there are contradictory views about this in this forum, even in answers by experts.

For instance, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188222/problem-with-babel-and-fontspec) question answered by egreg on July 2014 recommends  to load `fontspec` *after* `babel`.

However, egreg seems to contradict himself in his answer on October 2014 to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206847/problem-with-babel-package?rq=1) question and suggests to load `fontspec` *before* `babel`.

I am sure this confusion is simply due to my lack of understanding of the details. What am I missing, and what should be the correct loading order?

Comment: usually it makes no difference and anyway the format has changed since then as prior to 2015 xelatex defaulted to 7-bit OT1 font encoding, the same as pdflatex but sice then it defaults to TU (Unicode)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. Does it make any difference for luatex? I guess luatex was always unicode and should make no difference.

Comment: no the encoding was OT1 for lualatex until 2015 as well

Comment: Should be pointed out that unicode input encoding and unicode font encoding are different things. The default font encoding changed for both engines in 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't expect the loading order to make any difference: `babel` is about choosing language customisation and `fontspec` is about choosing fonts and these are only slightly related. Of course `babel` includes many different language files by many different authors and there may be some edge cases where loading in a different order solves some issue, but I am not aware of any.

Note that the linked questions are both to old versions pre 2015 when xelatex and lualatex defaulted (like pdftex) to the original TeX OT1 7bit encoding, so some babel files may have warned that that encoding could not support the requested language. However both lualatex and xelatex now default to (and typically only use) TU (Unicode) so the choice of language should not affect the encodings used, although of course not all fonts cover all language scripts.

Note the situation is different in (pdf)latex where you are restricted to 8bit encodings and so need to change encoding to support different languages. This means that `fontenc` (not `fontspec`) may need to be called before `babel` to avoid warnings, eg to load `LGR` encoding to support Greek, or T1 for most western Euroean languages, but even here I think in most cases the babel files will arrange the right encoding even if `fontenc` has not been explicitly loaded in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.15, Babel has  gained direct support for configuring fonts via fontspec. In this case, you can just use the `\babelfont` command and you do not need to load `fontspec` yourself explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\babelfont{rm}{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{Libertinus Sans}

\begin{document}
\Huge Hello World. \textsf{In Sans.}
\end{document}
```

See section 1.14 "Selecting Fonts" of the babel manual.